# jQuery DataTable - Get class of closest td element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Given a jQuery Datatable, how can I determine if a click occurs on a certain column?

I have a jQuery DataTable instance populated with assorted data that is a summary of a database record.  Currently, a click on a row opens a dialog box with all the fields of the corresponding database record.  What I want to do is open a second dialog box if the column clicked has a specified class 'comments'

Currently, I initialize the datatable via

```
timelineTable = $("#timeline_table").dataTable({
    "aLengthMenu" : [
        ["-1", "10", "25", "50", "100"],
        ["All", "10", "25", "50", "100"]
    ],
    "iDisplayLength" : -1,
    "aoColumnDefs" : [
        {"bVisible" : false, "aTargets" : [6, 8] },
        {"sClass" : "comments", "aTargets" : [7]} //adds class 'comments' to this column index
    ]
});
```

and have a click event bound to the dynamically populated rows:

```
$("#timeline_table").on("click", "tbody tr", timelineTableClickHandler);
```

This works fine for the default action of opening up the detail dialog, but I want to modify the function handler to

```
$("#timeline_table").on("click", "tbody tr", function(e){
  if ($(this).closest("td").hasClass("comments")) 
    //call secondary dialog open event
  else
    //call default dialog open event
});
```

However, `$(this).closest("td").hasClass("comments")` is returning undefined, and when I put a breakpoint on that in Firebug, the following commands and output result

```
$(this).attr("id") prints out row id
$(this).closest("td") prints out jQuery( )
$(this).closest("td").text() prints out "", should be 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here `this` is pointing to the `tr`, as you well know `td` is a child of `tr` so you cannot use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) on `this` to find the clicked td

Instead you can use the `target` property of the `event` to find the actual source of the event and find the `closest` td of that element

```
$("#timeline_table").on("click", "tbody tr", function(e){
  if ($(e.target).closest("td").hasClass("comments")) 
    //call secondary dialog open event
  else
    //call default dialog open event
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake I think.

tr has no closest td because td is a children of tr.
The closest element to tr is regularry tbody or table.

To access the td's you have to use:

```
$("#timeline_table").on("click", "tbody tr", function(e){
 if ($(e.target).children("td:eq(indexNo)").hasClass("comments")) 
  //call secondary dialog open event
 else
  //call default dialog open event
```

});